# Laravel 5.6.26 passport guzzle error when trying to register user using POSTMAN

Tags: guzzle, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

I am trying to implement Laravel Passport. When trying to register user and don't get a token back:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $guzzle = new Client;
    $response = $guzzle->post(
        url('oauth/token'),
        ['form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' => 'Px6fw3lwWy81Gwudx5eUa5xKHFG2jUDnNQ9qSPP5',
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
            ],]);
    return response(['auth' => json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true), 'user' => $user]);
```

I am using postman:
In headers I set: Accept: application/json
in body:

```
email:test@test.test
password:password
name:test
```

What parameter I am missing here? Where to find it? In my lavalel logs I see only errors:

```
 "message": "Client error: `POST http://homestead.test/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"message\":\"Client authentication failed\"}\n",
"exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException",
"file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php",
"line": 113,....
```

So which parameter I am missing?

Comment: can you check this with post man ? http://homestead.test/oauth/token send params by postman to this url and check result.